# Hero Image has white space left and right? First time coding

Tags: html, css

I'm learning to code - creative designer by trade but would like a better understanding of HTML and CSS.

I've added a hero image but I'm getting white gaps appear down the side. It doesn't appear to be padding as the text I've added buts up to the edge? Can anyone see a way to resolve this?

[www.georgehtdent.co.uk](http://www.georgehtdent.co.uk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by padding applied to `.container, .container-fluid`

[image: css padding gap]

```
.container, .container-fluid {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

You'll probably need to adjust other things after fixing the padding.

Comment: Hi @aziz may I ask what software did you use to record the screen into a gif?

Comment: @DannyH it's called [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) really good and also has compression options :-)

Comment: Thanks @aziz! will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="top-section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h1>Creative Design Headline</h1>
          <p>George Dent is a creative designer based in Northampton, UK. <br> He activates opportunities for brands and connects customers to products.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

don't use that div class called container-fluid.and remove the class called padding-0. that might just work for u.